# Connect to MySQL database from 4Dv12 or later version?

Tags: mysql, database, connection, 4d-database

Can anybody help me in connecting my MySQL database from my 4D database application. I have tried but still could not find any help. Please note that i want it without ODBC and want to directly connect to my MYSQL db.

Answer (score 1):

I have integrated MySQL with 4D without ODBC using this C compiled library

https://www.pluggers.nl/product-category/4d-plugins/

The price is WORTH EVERY PENNY. I used both their MySQL and PostgreSQL wrappers.
I talked to the developers, they have done just what you want. Provided a 4D component C library wrapper to target functionality of other databases.

It is VERY FAST.

If you decide to use the ODBC connector use this command to target a pre established ODBC connection on the machine.
http://doc.4d.com/4Dv15/4D/15/SQL-LOGIN.301-2007437.en.html

Also. ignore the connectivity API is for version 2004 and is not relevant to your question.

-James

Answer (score 0):

What I read is that 4D doesn't do this without the API (additional price of $59), API details seen [here](http://www.4d.com/products/4d2004/connectivity.html#4D%20for%20MySQL).
[Another option](http://www.4d.com/docs/CMU/CMU84458.HTM) I found, be out date, is to write something yourself in the C compiler which can talk to MySQL directly.

Answer (score 0):

You may connect via web service such as `SOAP`and `REST`. 
You may also retrieve both data in and out via `JASON`. 
Also, Since 4D now support PHP, you may `build an APPLICATION in php` that will do the migration or Synchronization.

But if you are looking for Direct Query, I don't know about the latest version of 4D, but as for 4Dv12 that would be bloody if you tried to build your own, since `the simplest way is to do it is via ODBC`.

Before, I tried to connect it via `EXTERNAL PROCESS` and `SERIAL COM` using .Net but it's just to risky, so i just Give up.